# Testing React Native Functional Component With Dependency on Promise

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

I've got a functional component in React Native.

```ts
import { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react-test-renderer/node_modules/@types/react";
import SpecialObject from "./SpecialObject";
import { getPromisedObject } from "./AccessFunctions";

export function PromiseDependencyComponent(): ReactElement {
  const [val, setVal] = useState<SpecialObject>(new SpecialObject());

  const promisedVal: Promise<SpecialObject> = getPromisedObject();

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      promisedVal.then( (obj) =>
        setVal(obj); 
      );
    }, 250);
  }, []);

  return (<Text>{val.getSomeField()}</Text>);
}
```

I'd like to be able to test that the promised `SpecialObject` is retrieved correctly when the component is rendered. This is what I've got now:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import PromiseDependencyComponent from "../PromiseDependencyComponent";

it("PromiseDependencyComponent renders correctly", () => {
  const componentRenderer = renderer.create(<PromiseDependencyComponent />);
  // I've also tried using timers and componentRenderer.update() and neither worked for me.
  const tree = componentRenderer.toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This test executes and nothing breaks, I'm just not seeing the same thing as I'm seeing when running the app. When I run the app, I see the promised value being displayed after a 250ms delay. But my problem is that I want to see the updated/promised value in my test snapshot.

So what I'm seeing in my app is something like this:

```xml
  <!-- This the updated/promised SpecialObject. -->
  <Text>5</Text>
```

But I'm getting something like this in my test snapshot:

```xml
  <!-- This just comes from a new instance of SpecialObject, which is the initialized component state. -->
  <Text>0</Text>
```

What's the simplest/cleanest way to invoke some sort of update on my component so that I can verify that the promise is fulfilled when the component is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a popular testing library for handling various testing scenarios in React and it is called [@testing-library/react](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/). I highly suggest you use it for your React component tests.

As for the question you ask, there are methods in `@testing-library/react` like `waitFor` and `await findBy...` and you can use them for your async tests. (See [Async Methods](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/))

So an example would be like this:

```js
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react"
import MyAsyncComponent from "./MyAsyncComponent"

describe("My Async Component", () => {
  it("Updates after promise resolves", async () => {
    render(<MyAsyncComponent/>)

    const myAsyncResult = await screen.findByText("5");

    expect(myAsyncResult).toBeInTheDocument();

  })
})
```

Comment: Interesting. This might work, but unfortunately I can't test this because the `render(...)` function is causing this error for me: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/422  I tried the fix, but the fix  didn't work for me.